# Hydrophone sensitivity rating

Tags: audio, audio-processing

If I use a hydrophone with the sensitivity given as: "-200 dB re 1V/μPa".

Question: How should I interpret this? Is it the voltage given at -200 dB SPL or??

All the Best!

Answer (score 1):

Hydrophones have a weird way of specifying sensitivity. $1V/ \mu Pa$ simply means $10^6 V/Pa$ which is frankly an idiotic unit.

You scale this by -200dB and  you get $ S = 10^{-4} V/Pa$ or $S = 0.1mV/Pa$ which is a much more reasonable representation.

This has NOTHING to do with dBSPL which is referenced to the human threshold of hearing. There is no reference needed here, since you are using Pascals directly.

Comment: Thank you Hilmar! So, if I then have S=0.1mV/Pa and the measured voltage goes up to 240 microvoltage at the hydrophone: could I then calculate the received sound pressure like this: 240uV / (0.1mV/Pa) = 2.4 Pa ?